# Is $|x+y|/\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ continuous?

Tags: functions, continuity

Let $g: \mathbb{R}^2 $ -> $\mathbb{R}$

[image: Function]

Can I just do the following?

$x^2+y^2\geq 2|x+y|$, so $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\geq \sqrt{2|x+y|}$, therefore $$\left|\frac{x+y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right|\leq\frac{|x+y|}{\sqrt{2|x+y|}}=\frac{\sqrt{|x+y|}}{\sqrt{2}},$$ which converges to $0$ as $x,y\to 0$, that means that it is continuous.

Or is that wrong?

Comment: polar coordinates?

Comment: What's $g(x,-x)$?

Comment: To solve these kind of problem we need to guess at first wheter the limit exists or not (as a not official rule let consider that "often" limit doesn't exist for more then one variable). When you do not have any good idea, use polar coordinatescan help to make  afirst guess. In that case we obtain $$|x+y|/\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\cos \theta-\sin \theta$$ which is very prone to do not exist. Then, as usual, it suffices find a path for which the limit is not equal to $1$.

Comment: $\cos\theta+\sin\theta$, maybe?  Also the function exists, the issue is if it converges to a common value for all $\theta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Set $y=mx$. For all $x,y\ne0$, the function is

$$\frac{|1+m|}{\sqrt{1+m^2}},$$ which is not constant.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

Note that

$$x^2+y^2\geq 2|x+y|$$

is not true for $x=y=\frac12$.

Check the path with $x=-y=t\to 0$.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote that
$$x^2+y^2>2|x+y|$$

which is false.
Take $x=y=\frac12$. it gives

$\frac 12>2$.

Answer (score 1):

Do not overthink this.  When $x=0, y\ne 0$ the function equals $1$, but if instead $y=-x$ with both of these arguments nonzero then the function equals $0$.  There is no single value for $f(0,0)$ that renders the function continuous because the algebraic expression for other values of $x$ and $y$ does not have a (single, invariant) limit as $(x,y)$ approaches $(0,0)$.